# MySQL / phpMyAdmin throws duplicity error on UNIQUE column when no duplicity occurs

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE pret_user (
    pret_user_index INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    pret_user_fname VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    pret_user_lname VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    pret_user_email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    pret_user_telegram_subscribe_token_hash VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
    pret_user_telegram_subscribe_token_hash_valid_until INT(15),
    pret_user_telegram_chat_id INT(15) UNIQUE,
    pret_user_telegram_subscribed TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

when I try to manually update a value of `pret_user_telegram_chat_id`, the following error is shown warning of duplicit value in a UNIQUE column even though there is no value with the same value (the table only has 4 rows so I checked manually). I've also noticed that while I'm trying to set the value to `5163196961`, the warning is about value `2147483647`. Any ideas as to what might be causing this would be much appreciated!

SQL:

```
UPDATE `d28748_admin`.`pret_user`
SET    `pret_user_telegram_chat_id` = '5163196931` 
WHERE  `pret_user`.`pret_user_index` = 2
```

Error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'pret_user_telegram_chat_id'
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

To get around the problem, I switched the column to VARCHAR for the time being and after that the problem disappeared, but I'd really like to get to the bottom of why this happened in case I have a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pret_user_telegram_chat_id is too small. [The max value for INT is 2147483647](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), even though you've specified 15 spots. You'll want BIGINT instead

Comment: Ahh, so the error message is a red herring. Good spot.